# eclipse missing file type with libGDX extensions

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I'm trying to draw text with the freetypefontgenerator and with the bitmapfont but somehow each time I'm trying to implement it into the code I got this error:

eclipse error with freetypefontgenerator and bitmapfont

[image]

that error comes also when I'm trying to use bitmapfont.

Comment: which version of JDK you're using ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in `FreeTypeFontGenerator` or not in `BitmapFont`, it is in Constructor of `Label` class.

```
new Label (CharSequence text, LabelStyle style)
```

> The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

`CharSequence` Interface having two default method `codePoints()` and `chars()`.
If source level of your project is lower then 1.8, then compiler doesn't allow to use default methods because Java 8 supports defaults methods in interface.

So, you have two options.

1. Rollback to JDK 7 (without default methods)
2. Set source level of your project to 1.8 (compiler allow to compile)